I cant configure LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL Django
I want to setting that after succesfully login with google it redirect me to the profile_detail.html page
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/polls/profile/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
views.py
def profile_detail(request):
    return render(request, "profile_detail.html")

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("logout/", views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('googleLogin/', views.googleLogin, name='googleLogin'),
    path('profile/', views.profile_detail, name='profile_detail'),
    path('profile_creation/', views.create_profile, name='profile_creation')
]


Can you share the "outer" urls.py?

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('polls.urls')),
path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Beware that the ?next=... takes precedence over the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.

@willeM_VanOnsem thank u so much! With last comment "Beware that the ?next=... takes precedence over the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. – " I fix my issue. In my google-login html page i had ?next=. And thats why it doesnt redirect me to the page what i need. I changed it and it works. And ur answear too works.Thanks!

Since polls.urls is included with path('', include('polls.urls')), that means the path is just /profile/, so:
# settings.py

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
We can make this more robust against path changes with reverse_lazy(…) [Django-doc]:
# settings.py

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('polls:profile_detail')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
